# Print string and integer LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, lcd

How do I print a string and integer on an LCD? Here is what I have tried:

```
int number = 2;
int result = (number + number);
lcd.print(number, DEC + " plus " + number, DEC + " equals " + result, DEC);
```

And the result is an error.  When I try:

```
lcd.print(number + "look");
```

or

```
lcd.print("1234 " + number);
```

Then the result on the LCD is "34 ", as it deleted the first two numbers!

I want it to print:

1234 2

Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lcd.print()` method takes a string or a number as an argument, but not both at once. Using the + operator for concatenation is not native to C strings. C strings are basically stored as pointers to the first character of the string. So when you tried `lcd.print("1234 " + number)` and got `"34 "`, what most likely happened is that you advanced the pointer, pointing to the first character of `"1234 "`(i.e. '1') by `number` (i.e. 2), thus making the pointer point to the **3rd** character in the string and thus making `lcd.print()` display `"34 "`. 
In order to print something that contains both strings and integers, the most straightforward way is to convert each piece to an Arduino string and then concatenate them, using the + operator like you did earlier.

```
    lcd.print(String("1234 ") + String(number));
    lcd.print(String(number) + String(" plus ") + String(number) + String(" equals ") + String(result));
```

These are some examples. You could also use create a sufficiently large `char` buffer and use `sprintf()` from `stdio.h` to build a string made up of integers and strings. Look up a textbook on C/C++ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I printed the string and the integer on the same line by moving the cursor like this :

```
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);    <----------Column 0 , Line 1
   lcd.print("This code failed");
   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);    <----------Column 0 , Line 2
   lcd.print("Error Code = ");
   lcd.setCursor(13, 1); <-change the cursor for the INT. Column 13 , Line 2
   lcd.print(int);
```

Comment: What happens if a first error code is, say, 1234, then another one is 57... the display would show "5734" right?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this:

```
lcd.print(number, DEC + " plus " + number, DEC + " equals " + result, DEC);
```

It is the number of parameters and the assumption that plus will concatenate string literals.

```
lcd.print("1234 " + number);
```

This gives "34 " when number is 2. Why? This is because that is the result of adding 2 to the string literal pointer, i.e. the string starting at the character "3". Please use separate print statements instead:

```
lcd.print("1234 ");
lcd.print(number);
```

Do not use String to concatenate strings. That is a waste of SRAM, processing and has a risk of heap fragmentation. Simply a bad idea in small scale embedded systems such as AVR.

To understand these errors you should go back and read about strings and string literals in C/C++ (compared to Java :).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=0;
float b=10.01;

char str[16];

sprintf(str,"a=%d, b=%.2f, c=%d", a, b, 2); // use sprintf() to compose the string str

lcd.print(str);
```

The output will be 'a=0, b=10.01, c=2'